# Tor won't connect even through bridges

Tags: bridge, socks, connection

Using the Tor browser bundle, I can't connect to Tor at the Port Angeles, Washington library. I have tried all the connection options including requesting some bridges. When trying to connect, the progress bar just hangs and nothing happens even after several minutes. My log:

```
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/11/19, 01:50:29.837 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/home/q/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc.orig.1" 
7/11/19, 01:50:30.817 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport 
7/11/19, 01:50:30.822 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport 
7/11/19, 01:50:31.359 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay 
7/11/19, 01:50:31.868 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay 
7/11/19, 01:50:32.179 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done 
7/11/19, 01:50:32.182 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
7/11/19, 01:50:32.484 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus 
7/11/19, 01:50:32.795 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Unnamed' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (146.196.65.18:443) based on the configured Bridge address. 
7/11/19, 01:50:32.795 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (fresh): $642201EDF4BF5E3898E4F34B930032B00E3BA27C~Unnamed at 146.196.65.18 
7/11/19, 01:50:33.238 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:34.241 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:35.246 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:36.250 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:37.254 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:38.258 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:39.550 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus 
7/11/19, 01:50:41.292 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 92.236.245.23:45877 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.258 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.465 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40% (loading_keys): Loading authority key certs 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.660 [NOTICE] The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.661 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45% (requesting_descriptors): Asking for relay descriptors 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6470, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 100% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.) 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:43.664 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.170 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] The current consensus contains exit nodes. Tor can build exit and internal paths. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:44.827 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:45.236 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:45.236 [NOTICE] Ignoring directory request, since no bridge nodes are available yet. 
7/11/19, 01:50:49.830 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 55% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors 
7/11/19, 01:50:49.480 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 61% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors 
7/11/19, 01:50:49.816 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 67% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors 
7/11/19, 01:52:41.690 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 178.128.164.36:34415 ("general SOCKS server failure")
```

Answer (score 0):

The bridge you are using is probably blocked. Get a private bridge by going [here](https://bridges.torproject.org/). Do not share though or else it may become blocked also.